# Native android app login via api using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Is there any sample app or boilerplate with best practices on login activity to a remote api ? I need a login activity which makes a POST call to an HTTP api (jsonp) and use the auth token returned to handle the rest of the session. I am using the Android Studio for Development.

Comment: search for AccountManager

Answer (score 0):

- Make a request using volley to get the token, more on volley: [Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)
- Save the token on SharedPreferences, see here: A[ndroid User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

The thing is, when the user starts the app, you check (on SharedPreferences) whether (s)he has a token, if not make the request.